# Recovering an affine group scheme from its representations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

I want to understand the proof of recovering an affine group scheme from its category of representations which is presented as proposition 2.8 in Milne's notes [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.pdf).

1. Firstly I want to understand the group scheme $GL_X$ for a $k$-vector space $X$. I know it is isomorphic (non-canonically) to $GL_n$, by fixing a basis, which is represented by the $k$-algebra $k[X_{ij},Y]/(Y\cdot\det(X_{ij})-1)$. I want to what to know which $k$-algebra represents $GL_X$ for a $k$-vector space $X$. More specifically what is the $A$ which satisfies $$\operatorname{Hom}_{k-alg}(A,R)=\left \{f:X\otimes R\rightarrow X\otimes R \mid f \text{ is an } R-\text{linear isomorphism}\right \}.$$

Taking $C_X$ to be the full subcategory of $Rep_k(G)$ generated by objects isomorphic to subquotients of finite direct sums and tensor products of $X$ and $X^{\vee}$   and $Aut^\otimes(\omega| C_X)$ to be the functor sending $R$ to tensor automorphisms (endomorphisms due to rigidity) of the functor $\phi_R\circ\omega|_{C_X}$ ($\omega$ is the forgetful functor, $\phi_R$ is the functor from vacrtor spaces to R modules $V\mapsto V\otimes R$) we get
$Aut^\otimes(\omega| C_X)(R)\subset GL_X(R)$.

2. Now, $G_X=Img(G\rightarrow GL_X)$ which is mentioned as a closed subgroup of $GL_X$. I want to know why image is representable and also closed inside $GL_X$ and how $G_X(R)$ lies inside $Aut^\otimes(\omega| C_X)(R)$.

Now Chevalleys theorem says that $G_X$ is a stabilizer of a 1- dimensional subspace of a finite dimensional $GL_X$ representation. $Aut^\otimes(\omega| C_X)$ also stabilizes that subspace and contains $G_X$. But how to conclude rigorously  that they are equal.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to question (1) is well explained in "The Book of Involutions" by Merkurjev, Rost, Knus, and Tignol - see 20.2, example (3). For convenience, I'll mention here that the representing algebra is $S(A^{\ast})[1/N]$, where $A = \operatorname{End}_{k}(X)$, $S(A^{\ast})$ is the symmetric algebra of the dual $A^{\ast}$, and $N \colon A \to k$ is the norm map, viewed as an element of $S^{n}(A^{\ast})$.

Comment: @bluebird: For any commutative ring $k$ and any $k$-linear endomorphism $\phi$ of $k^n$ with coefficients in $k$, there is a determinant $det(A)$ defined and from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem it follows $\phi$ is an invertible map iff $det(A)$ is a unit (see the link). What is your aim: Do you seek an "intrinsic"definition of the coordinate ring $A$ not using a basis for $X$ or do you seek a definition valid for infinite dimensional vector spaces? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455761/how-is-the-determinant-related-to-the-inverse-of-matrix/4328310#4328310

Comment: In Jantzens book "Representations of algebraic gorups" he defines and studies  the group scheme $GL_A(E)$ for any finite rank projective $A$-module $E$ on any commutative unital ring $A$. This is defined using the "language of representable functors".

Comment: @AlexWertheim, thank you very much. This is the algebra I was looking for. Now proceeding for (2), I know that any algebraic subgroup of an algebraic group will be closed, but then how to prove that image of a representation is algebraic subgroup?

Comment: @hm2020, I was looking for $A$ without using the basis of $X$ which is finite dimensional. Does there exists a definition which also extends to infinite dimensional case. Jantzen's book does it for finitely generated projective.

Comment: @bluebird - Im not so sure it is possible to do anything sensible with schemes or group schemes of infinite type over a field or a Dedekind domain. For a scheme of infinite type over a field we cannot define the notion "regularity". There are many constructions that "break down" when schemes become infinite dimensional.

Comment: @bluebird: As an example: In Hartshorne; CH.I.Prop.5.2 they prove the following inequality for any Noetherian local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m},k):(*)krdim(A) \leq dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$. We say $A$ is a regular local ring if this is an equality. If $A$ is the localization of a ring of infinite type over a Dedekind domain the inequality $(*)$ does not make any sense.

Comment: @bluebird - If $A:=k[x_1,x_2,...,]$ is a polynomial ring on a countably infinite set of variables and if $I\subseteq A$ is an ideal generated by a finite set of polynomials and consider $B:=A/I$. Let $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq B$ be a prime ideal and let $R:=B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Both entities $krdim(R)$ and $dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ are countably infinite. How do you make sense of the "inequality" $krdim(R) \leq dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ when both numbers are infinite?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "@hm2020, I was looking for A without using the basis of X which is finite dimensional. Does there exists a definition which also extends to infinite dimensional case. Jantzen's book does it for finitely generated projective. –
bluebird yesterday"

**Answer:** @bluebird - If $A:=k[x_1,x_2,...]$ is a polynomial ring on a countably infinite set of variables $x_i$ and if $I\subseteq A$ is an ideal generated by a finite set of polynomials, consider $B:=A/I$. Let $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq B$ be a prime ideal and let $R:=B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Both entities $krdim(R)$ and $dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ are countably infinite. How do you make sense of the "inequality" $krdim(R) \leq dim_k(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ when both numbers are infinite? You need this type of inequality to define the notion "regular local ring" and it does not make any sense to speak of $\infty \leq \infty$.